Are there any antisymmetric translation invariant and rotation invariant functions?
I'm trying to create an antisymmetric function over vectors that is translation and rotation invariant, but I haven't had much success.
So if I have a set of vectors like:
$$
\{\vec{a}, \vec{b}\}
$$
I want the function to satisfy antisymmetry:
$$
f(\vec{a}, \vec{b}) = -f(\vec{b}, \vec{a})
$$
I also want the function to satisfy translation invariance:
$$
f(\vec{a} + \vec{d}, \vec{b}+ \vec{d}) = f(\vec{a}, \vec{b})
$$
And finally I want it to satisfy rotation invariance such that:
$$
 {\displaystyle R={\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta &-\sin \theta \\\sin \theta &\cos \theta \end{bmatrix}}}\\
[\vec{a'},\vec{b'}] =R[\vec{a},\vec{b}]\\
f(\vec{a'},\vec{b'}) = f(\vec{a}, \vec{b})
$$
My first idea is was to center the input matrix and then compute the determinant. Centering the matrix would make the function translation invariant, and the determinant is already antisymmetric and rotation invariant. Thus it would be something like this:
$$
\bar{x} = \frac{1}{2} (a_{0} + b_{0})\\
\bar{y} = \frac{1}{2} (a_1 + b_1)\\
\vec{d} = (\bar{x}, \bar{y})\\
f(\vec{a}, \vec{b}) = \det\left(\left[\vec{a} - \vec{d}, \vec{b} - \vec{d}\right]\right)
$$
However, centering a matrix results in a singular matrix, which makes the determinant zero. While this is technically a solution, I'm not interested in a trivial solution.
This makes me wonder, is it even possible to construct a non trivial function with these properties?

Can you specify which sets you're working on?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm mostly thinking of matrices as column vectors, and I want the operation to be invariant to operations rotations and translations of those column vectors.

looks like a pseudoscalar might do the job https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscalar

I finally found that if I center it at a different point other that the origin the matrix is non singular, and it works.

The only function that fits the bill is the zero function.
For any two vectors $x$ and $y$, let $d=\frac{x+y}{2},\,v=\frac{x-y}{2}$ and $R$ be any rotation that rotates $\pm v$ to $\mp v$. Then
$$
f(x,y)=f(v+d,-v+d)=f(v,-v)=f(Rv,R(-v))=f(-v,v)=-f(v,-v).
$$
Therefore $f(v,-v)=0$ and $f(x,y)=0$.
